# NFS /exports/media won't automount during boot

Tags: boot, mount, nfs, webmin

I'm using Webmin 1.580 with Ubuntu 12.04 and created an NFS export (export/media) which works perfectly fine after manually enabling the export, but when I reboot the system it tells me that it is unable to mount it, and I need to skip it in order to resume booting. How can I find out the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I've already seen that, it seems to be a common issue these days. I'm also almost sure I've already solved the same problem on one of my machines, but unfortunately I don't remember how. What I remember is that was a dependency problem (NFS mountpoints mounted before the network was up). Try this solution https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118251 and good luck.

EDIT: sorry, if there isn't any `/etc/rc.conf` in Ubuntu, you could try [this solution](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/444556-nfs-does-not-mount-boot.html#post2214156). In case, you could also try to look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1329355).

Comment: thanks. I checked out your link, and it says to edit /etc/rc.conf but I don't have this file.